# Disable stylecop in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

I have to convert a C# project in Visual Studio 2008. I only need to run it and I don't really need the code since I will restart from scratch. I only need to see the windows. When I open it, I got 1900 errors that (after searching) seems to come from Stylecop. I haven't heard about this software before. So now, I want to disable it. I tried with creating a Settings.StyleCop file in the solution folder with the folowwing lines:

```
    <StyleCopSettings Version="105">
      <GlobalSettings>
        <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
      </GlobalSettings>
   </StyleCopSettings>
```

It seems to have worked for a few builds, but not anymore... Strangely, I don't see Stylecop in my add/remove programs in the control panel, and I don't have any menus about it in Visual Studio. I want to disable it or remove it if I have to, but I am out of ideas. Or maybe the errors are from another software? Here is a few examples:

SA1612: The param tags in the documentation header must match the parameters list

SA1611: The documentation header must contain param tags matching the element's parameter list.

SA1616: The returns section in the documentation header must not be empty.

EDIT : If I ask my question in an other way, is it possible that the project has been compiled with Stylecop on a machine and even if (I think) I don't have Stylecop on my machine, the errors would still show?

Comment: You get Errors or Warnings from StyleCop? When I run StyleCop I get Warnings which don't lead compiler errors.

Comment: That's another thing I don't understand, it is errors and not warnings. On the websites I saw, it always seems to be warnings...

Comment: Do you have Resharper installed as well?

Comment: No I don't have Resharper, but I finally found a solution. I found the xml property StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings in each of the csproj files, and it was set to false. I set it to true, and now I can compile. So it solves my problem. Thanks!